# How to view a chaincode definition?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The Fabric documentation explains in detail what a chaincode definition is and which role it plays for the lifecycle and governance of a chaincode. It says, that an organisation needs to approve a definition in order to use the chaincode. What it doesn't explain - imho - is, how to VIEW a chaincode defintion prior approving it.

**Question:** Is there a command to view a chaincode definition? Or is there another workflow that I missed, so that an organization can study the definition before approving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to the approval is the definition.  You can think of a chaincode definition as being all the parameters required to execute and validate a chaincode transaction.  You supply the definition via [the parameters you see in the documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/chaincode_lifecycle.html#step-three-approve-a-chaincode-definition-for-your-organization), so, it is in fact impossible to perform the approval without already knowing the definition.

Generally speaking, the definition is agreed to out of band, and then all participating organization approve the externally agreed to definition.  However, if you are on a network and wishing to discover what other members have approved, or what definitions have committed, there are a number of query utilities provided via the peer CLI.  You can see what definition an org has approved using the [queryapproved subcommand](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerlifecycle.html#peer-lifecycle-chaincode-queryapproved), you can see what orgs have approved a particular definition using the [checkcommitreadiness subcommand](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerlifecycle.html#peer-lifecycle-chaincode-checkcommitreadiness), and you can view the currently committed definition using the [querycommitted subcommand](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerlifecycle.html#peer-lifecycle-chaincode-querycommitted) or by using the [queryinstalled subcommand](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerlifecycle.html#peer-lifecycle-chaincode-queryinstalled).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Each organization have to agree on a chaincode package which have a unique hash value and a label, they all may get the chaincode package from a developer and if someone try to change something on chaincode, that chaincode package will give different hash value compare to others.

Step 2: Each organization will install that chaincode package on there peers.

Step 3: After that each organization get an identical Package ID which is a combination on that chaincode package's hash value and label. You can get it by "peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled" command.

step 4: Now you can approve that identical Package ID with channelID, name, version, init-required etc etc from your organization. Before approval you can also check the checkcommitreadiness.

step 5: TO check the checkcommitreadiness of that identical Package ID with  channelID, name, version, init-required, sequence 1 etc etc follow the command given below. If it gets enough approval, It's ready for commit.

So each organization will give approval of it's own chaincode with other definitions like channelID, name, version, init-required etc etc & due to the system a fraudulent activity will not get enough approval.

```
Check whether a chaincode definition is ready to be committed on a channel.

Usage:
  peer lifecycle chaincode checkcommitreadiness [flags]

Flags:
      --channel-config-policy string   The endorsement policy associated to this chaincode specified as a channel config policy reference
  -C, --channelID string               The channel on which this command should be executed
      --collections-config string      The fully qualified path to the collection JSON file including the file name
      --connectionProfile string       The fully qualified path to the connection profile that provides the necessary connection information for the network. Note: currently only supported for providing peer connection information
  -E, --endorsement-plugin string      The name of the endorsement plugin to be used for this chaincode
  -h, --help                           help for checkcommitreadiness
      --init-required                  Whether the chaincode requires invoking 'init'
  -n, --name string                    Name of the chaincode
  -O, --output string                  The output format for query results. Default is human-readable plain-text. json is currently the only supported format.
      --peerAddresses stringArray      The addresses of the peers to connect to
      --sequence int                   The sequence number of the chaincode definition for the channel (default 1)
      --signature-policy string        The endorsement policy associated to this chaincode specified as a signature policy
      --tlsRootCertFiles stringArray   If TLS is enabled, the paths to the TLS root cert files of the peers to connect to. The order and number of certs specified should match the --peerAddresses flag
  -V, --validation-plugin string       The name of the validation plugin to be used for this chaincode
  -v, --version string                 Version of the chaincode

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --connTimeout duration                Timeout for client to connect (default 3s)
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
```

As answered before [chaincode defination is the combination of parameters](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/chaincode_lifecycle.html#step-three-approve-a-chaincode-definition-for-your-organization).